# onclick events fails to work on images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a a script that pops up an alert on click of a text. I attached this same script to an image and it fails to work. i

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.coverimage').on('click', function (event) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Get the `href` value of the clicked anchor
        var paramValue = href.split('=')[1]; // Get the value after =
        $('#news_div').load('newsarea.asp?news_id='+paramValue);
        alert ('page works fine')

    });
});

<a href="#"><img src="imgs/newsimage.png" width="23" height="16" class="coverimage" /></a>
```

Comment: ajax? need event delegation...

Comment: you dont have an href in your image. paramValue is null

Comment: use "<a href=" and call your script !

Comment: @sam, sorry i've edited my script and add a href tag to it. its done like that already but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an 'href' attribute of you image which doesn't exist. With that said, why not simply wrap your image inside an `<a>` tag and not use any jQuery at all?

```
<a href="http://your_url_here"><img src="../imgs/news_icon.png" width="36" height="36" class="coverimage" border="0" /></a>
```

If you want to use jQuery, you can do something like this. I see you need to get a news_id property. You can use data- attributes to embed your news ID value like such:

```
<img src="../imgs/news_icon.png" width="36" height="36" class="coverimage" data-news-id="<%= /* Output news_id value */ %>" />
```

And your javascript can then look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.coverimage').on('click', function (event) {
        var newsId = $(this).data('newsId'); // data-value-name becomes 'valueName' in JavaScript
        $('#news_div').load('newsarea.asp?news_id='+newsId);
        alert ('page works fine')

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on mine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.coverimage').on('click', function (event) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Get the `href` value of the clicked anchor
    var paramValue = href.split('=')[1]; // Get the value after =
    $('#news_div').load('newsarea.asp?news_id='+paramValue);
    alert ('page works fine');

});
});



<a href="#" class="coverimage"><img src="imgs/newsimage.png" width="23" height="16"/></a>
```

Your class should be on the anchor not on the image.